# "through any vehicles" is this an idiom?

Tags: phrases, idioms

In a letter I came across a sentence

> Despite of feeling bad for losing one of the best students so far yet for any further specific info/ query you are welcome to get in touch with me through any vehicles during business hours.

Is "through any vehicles" an idiom? I googled `"through any vehicles" idiom` without any success.

Comment: @tchrist it looks like a slightly changed output of the translator.

Answer (score 6):

It's not really an idiom, it's just using a perhaps less-known definition of **vehicle**. From Merriam-Webster:

> **vehicle**, *noun* …**2:** an agent of transmission : carrier

In the given context, the implied idea is *vehicle of communication*. It's probably not the most common word to use in that context (**method** or **medium** come to my mind first), but it's definitely not unheard of. There are some other things going on in that sentence that make me think that the author is not a native English speaker, but I think the intent is pretty clear.

Comment: You are right. The letter sounds funny:)

Comment: It is such a usage, but is incorrect because the plural is used; it should be singular.  The preposition _through_ is a bit odd. A more conventional usage would be something like _get in touch using any vehicle_.

Comment: @mgkrebbs: It would still be a daft choice of words anyway. Per Cameron's definition, a *vehicle of communication* is usually an *agent, intermediary* who/which carries/clarifies a message. The "more conventional usage" would be something like *get in touch using any **means*** - except "post / email" wouldn't really fit since the writer specifies "business hours". Presumably he only expects telephone or visit in person, but he's trying to sound more expansive and all-embracing.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find this phrase in my dictionary of phrasal verbs and idioms. The "vehicles" word might be replaced for mail, phone... or anything that you can contact with him/her.